# Connect centroids of a grid in python using shapely, geopandas and indexing

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I'm new to the world of programming and as of now i'm writing a program for my thesis.

I'm using Python to do the following:

- I have a closed polygon, were i create a however big grid made of boxes in shapely.
- The grid-boxes are indexed beginning at the bottom left, then going up, then going down and one to the right: 
  I need these boxes to discretize the polygon. Which i could do successfully:
  [image: Valid boxes of the grid (within the polygon)]

Now: i got the centroids of each valid box and their respective x and y- coordinates. Now i want to link the centroids of the boxes for each x-value like this:

[image: Aim]

I tried to link them using two for-loops:

```
def pathplanning_on_vb(Boxes_within, Box_edge_length):
    '''This function takes the gridboxes within the closed polygon(Boxes_within), 
    gives me the coordinates (x- and y-values) of their centerpoints 
    and aims to deliver LineStrings, 
    which connect the centers of the gridboxes vertically! 
    As of now, it only delivers vertical lines from ymin to ymax over xmin to xmax.'''

    centerpoints = Boxes_within.centroid
    x_coords = centerpoints.geometry.x 
    y_coords = centerpoints.geometry.y
    for x in x_coords:
        for y in y_coords:
            path.append(LineString([(x, y), (x, y + Box_edge_length)]))
```

But this gives me lines that go from miny to maxy (which is only logical)

[image: output]

Is there a way to create the lines for each specific x- AND y-value, so as to only link the centroids of the gridboxes (!) vertically?
Or does anybody have some suggestions as how i should perform this task?

**Further infos:**

the centerpoints are a geoseries file, the x_ and y_coords are geodataframes. They each respectively still have the initial boxnumber in their first column (so the first entry of x_ and y_coords is '16'). Is this a way of linking them back together?

Thank you for your attention and help

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*trim the lines for each specific x-value*"? Please, consider adding an example of input data and the expected output. Currently, it's not clear what you are trying to achieve (at least for me).

Comment: Of course! I added the output as of now (see the hyperlink "output"). The output i expect is to be seen in my post ("Aim"). I want to connect the centers of my (valid) gridboxes (see "valid boxes of the grid") in such a manner, that they are connected vertically. Example: Lets say the leftmost boxes are x = 1, and y = 3 and 4. So i want to automatically generate a line between (1,3) and (1,4). Then in the next column of x = 2, we have the boxes for y= 2, 3, 4, 5. So i want to have LineStrings between (2,2), (2,3), (2,4), (2,5) etc...